# Passing command arguments in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I need to pass in three file names and an integer as arguments for the main function.

example command:

```
% gcc lab4.c infile1.txt infile2.txt output.txt 0
```

---

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

the file names can then be used as needed `argv[1]` etc...

The first three are no problem but how would I change formatting to accommodate the integer?

Using emacs if that makes a difference

Answer (score 3):

You can get the integer properly this way:

```
int i=atoi(argv[4]);
printf("%d\n",i);
```

However, do not forget to test if the argv[4] key is defined:

```
if(argc<=4)
  return EXIT_FAILURE;

int i=atoi(argv[4]);
printf("%d\n",i);
```